# How to solve duplication error when loading both espresso web and core in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I'm trying to use Android Espresso Web for my automation test.

After adding it to the build.gradle file like shown below, I get a "DuplicateFileException" exception.

According to the [API](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/web/), both of the dependancies should be present in the build.gradle file so I don't understand why I get a duplication exception and how to solve it.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':CompanyAAA:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForStagingDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties
     File1: /Users/mayabechler-speicher/CompanyAAA-Android/CompanyAAA/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support.test.espresso/espresso-web/2.2.2/jars/classes.jar
     File2: /Users/mayabechler-speicher/CompanyAAA-Android/CompanyAAA/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support.test.espresso/espresso-core/2.2.2/jars/classes.jar

[4:24]  
// Espresso core
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

   // Espresso web
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
```

Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Espresso-web import causes duplicateFileException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800924/espresso-web-import-causes-duplicatefileexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google's Android Testing Support Library Examples, you don't need to declare both, if your existing app depends on webviews.

Check this configuration:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 24
>     buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.example.android.testing.espresso.web.BasicSample"
>         minSdkVersion 10
>         targetSdkVersion 24
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>
>         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>     }
>     lintOptions {
>         abortOnError false
>     }
>     productFlavors {
>     }
>     packagingOptions {
>       exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
>       exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     // App dependencies
>     compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:' + rootProject.supportLibVersion;
>     compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
>     // Testing-only dependencies
>     // Force usage of support annotations in the test app, since it is internally used by the runner module.
>     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:' + rootProject.supportLibVersion;
>     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:' + rootProject.runnerVersion;
>     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:' + rootProject.rulesVersion;
>     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:' + rootProject.espressoVersion;
> }
> ```
>
> From: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/WebBasicSample/app/build.gradle

If you need both, open your build.gradle file and add:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
}
```

It should work